# Send an Email Perl Using MIME::Lite

Tags: perl, mime, mime-types, perl-module

I am just trying to send a basic email using Perl and MIME::Lite and I am receiving the following error: SMTP mail() command failed: 5.1.7 Invalid adderess
Here is my code:

```
#!perl

use MIME::Lite;

#Create Mail
$msg = MIME::Lite->new(
From =>'someone@someplace.com',
To =>'someone@someplace.com',
Cc =>'some@other.com',
Subject =>'Subject Test',
Data =>"Data Test"
);

#Send Mail
$msg->send( "smtp", "mail.place.com" );
```

Thanks.

I ended up solving it:

```
sub EMailReport
{
    use MIME::Lite;

    my $theSubject = "Sub";

    my $theData = "Data";

    my $theEmail = MIME::Lite->new(
    From     =>'From@someplace.somewhere.com',
    To       =>'fistname.lastname@company.com',
    Subject  =>$theSubject,
    Data     =>$theData
    );

    $theEmail->add( "Type" => "multipart/mixed" );

    $theEmail->send( "smtp", "somemail.company.com" );
}
```

Comment: The correct and full error message is [`501 5.1.7 Invalid Address`](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=%22501+5.1.7+Invalid+Address%22). Next time use copy & paste, this eliminates these sort of mistakes. Obviously, [the syntax of the recipient addresses is wrong](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-4.2.2). Post your real code, after your redaction it no longer exhibits the problem.

Comment: $theEmail->add( "Type" => "multipart/mixed" ); does not need to be a separate line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [pass to send() the smtp arguments](http://p3rl.org/MIME%3a%3aLite#Change_how_messages_are_sent) I think.